# issue while setting focus to text box after multiple post back events

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, updatepanel

On my page there is update panel and one text box and button inside same update panel. after i set enter key as default button for update panel. After multiple post back actually after third post back focus is set to the back button of browser. where as i want to set focus to the text box. i tried to set focus to the first text box by using below option which i have written at last line of button event.

```
1. option => Page.SetFocus(txtOrdertoAdd.ClientID);
2. option => txtOrdertoAdd.Focus();
3. option => Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "Script", "SetFocus(" + txtOrdertoAdd.ClientID + ");</script>");
4. option => ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "selectAndFocus", "$get('" + txtOrdertoAdd.ClientID + "').focus();", true);
```

i am facing this wired issue specifically in IE where its working fine in fire fox and chrome.Can any one how can i resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

```
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
</asp:ScriptManager>
    <div>
        <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
            <ContentTemplate>
                 <asp:Panel runat="server" ID="Panel1" DefaultButton="Button1">
                     <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                     <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClick="Button1_Click" />
                </asp:Panel>
            </ContentTemplate>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
```

and this:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TextBox1.Text = TextBox1.Text + "1";
    TextBox1.Focus();
}
```

Works fine on IE11.

Can you show what you have?